# Call to a member function hasAnyRole() on null

Tags: laravel, middleware

I am new on laravel. I am actually having a problem with my middleware. I already registered it on Kernel.php file.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){

   $user = Auth::user();

    if($user->hasAnyRole('school'))
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      

    return redirect('login');
}
```

here is my User model

```
public function roles(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function hasAnyRoles(){

        return null !== $this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first();
    }

     public function hasAnyRole(){
     return null !== $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
     }
```

Comment: That means your $user variable is null, is that correct?

Comment: Are you using `spatie`?

Comment: No I am not using Spatie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flipping the logic and also checking if logged in.
Do a `(Auth::check()` :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
  if (Auth::check()) {
     $user = Auth::user();
     if($user->hasAnyRole('school'))
     {
        return $next($request);
     }
  } else {
      return redirect('login'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am no longer having that error. Now I getting this  This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. I am often getting while working with middleware. I cleared my cookies but it's still not working.